# How to create files which are named by the elements of a column stored in a file?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a file which contains two columns, the first one contains the name and the second one contains the measurements for the corresponding names.

I need to create files with the name of the measurements, and each measurement has the corresponding measurement for it.

In other words, I need to make files which are named by the first column and they contain the element of the second column (but the same line).

I thought of the following code:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.genfromtxt('file.txt', dtype=(str))
arr_0=arr[:,0]
arr_1=arr[:,1]
numrows = len(arr)
for i in range (0,6):
    name=arr_0[i]
    value=arr_1[i]
    np.savetxt(name, int(value))
    i=i+1
```

My code does not work, can you tell me what should be changed and why?

FYI, I tried np.savetxt(name,value) and this did not work either!

The file:

```
el02_f125lp_wht_r.fits  520758208.
el02_f140lp_wht_r.fits  758538560.
el02_f150lp_wht_r.fits  1.030201E9
el02_f336w_wht_r.fits  30627980.
el02_f680n_wht_r.fits  18258366.
el02_f775w_wht_r.fits  3536094.
el02_fq508n_wht_r.fits  58293324.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works...

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', dtype=str)

for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    np.savetxt(arr[i, 0], [float(arr[i, 1])])   # int -> float
```

Comment: The code does not work! 

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-4f4be9ed72f2> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(0, len(arr)):
----> 2     np.savetxt(arr[i, 0], arr[i, 1])
      3 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments)
   1032                 ncol = len(X.dtype.descr)
   1033         else:
-> 1034             ncol = X.shape[1]
   1035 
   1036         iscomplex_X = np.iscomplexobj(X)

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Could you please show the content of your input file?

Comment: I have added the file to the post.

Comment: Ok,  I thought that your measurements are integers (looking at your code). If they are float then see my corrected variant.

Comment: Yes I figured that.
Thank you,  :)

Comment: If my variant solves your your problem, please mark it as a solution. Thank you.